# Prepend data to a FlatList on react native web, while maintaining visible content

Tags: react-native-flatlist, react-native-web, flatlist

Is it possible to implement a Flatlist with **react native web** where you prepend data while maintaining the visible content?

Right now, it jumps to the top of the Flatlist when you prepend something. I am using `onContentSizeChange` to force move the scroll position after an update, but the experience is terrible as there is sometimes a huge delay before the update.
Check this slack to see what I mean: https://snack.expo.io/@divone/prepend-data-to-flatlist-on-web

Was anyone successful in implementing a Chat-like Flatlist with React Native Web? If yes, how to achieve it?

---

**EDIT**: I discovered that on react native web, content visibility is automatically maintained when you prepend data **IF AND ONLY IF** the scroll bar is not at the top of the screen. ([snack](https://snack.expo.io/@divone/content-visibility-maintained-if-not-scrolled-all-the-way-up))

So my question still stands... how to prepend data and maintain visiblity even if the scrollbar is scrolled all the way up?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/1860#issuecomment-656115581

Comment: fyi, onContentSizeChange is not reliable. it will stop getting updated after the size has increased to a certain number due to optimisations for large flat lists, and you'll end up with delta being 0. also, the change could be triggered multiple times during a single append.

Comment: @Prasanth yeah I had a lot of issues with onContentSizeChange, so I am definitely looking for an alternative.

Comment: @SKarpov I already tried this solution. I end up with an extremely stiff scrolling (in comparison to the smooth scrolling you normally get). It's not really usable in a finished product, imo...

Answer (score 0):

You could invert your flatlist and then also reverse your data perspective. I mean when you reverse the flatlist's direction you add data at the end of it and no jump happend then. I modify your shared code and paste it below to be clear what I said hope it helps:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';

let lastContentHeight = 0;
let lastY = 0;

export default function App() {
const [data, setdata] = React.useState([]);

const flatlist = React.useRef();

const addData = React.useCallback(() => {
    const first =  data.length ? data[data.length-1].key : 1;
    const newArray = [];
    for (let i = first ; i <first+ 15; i++) {
        newArray.push({ key: i });
    }
    setdata([ ...data,...newArray]);
}, [data]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    addData();
}, []);

// const onContentSizeChange = (contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
//  const delta = contentHeight - lastContentHeight;
//  const newY = lastY + delta;
//  flatlist.current.scrollToOffset({ animated: false, offset: newY });
//  lastY = newY;
//  lastContentHeight = contentHeight;
// };

const onScroll = ({
    nativeEvent: {
        contentOffset: { y },
    },
}) => {
    lastY = y;
};

return (
    <View style={{ height: 600 }}>
        <Button onPress={addData} title="Prepend data" />
        <FlatList
  inverted
            ref={flatlist}
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={{ padding: 80 }}>{item.key}</Text>}
            // onContentSizeChange={onContentSizeChange}
            onScroll={onScroll}
        />
    </View>
);
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately, `inverted` does not work well on web. The mouse wheel scrolling becomes inverted too (at least on chrome). Also, I would like to know how to prepend data in general, no matter if prepending means adding to the top (normal) or the bottom (inverted) of the screen.